# What to do if in Unity the center of mass is determined incorrectly and does not change when the parts in the object are moved?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

In my project there is an object consisting of several other objects. It constantly falls because its center of mass is displaced and defined incorrectly. In addition, after starting the game, the center of mass of the object begins to fall downwards endlessly. I will be very grateful if someone knows how to fix this.

Displacing parts and re-creating the "Empty" and adding objects to it did not help. The center of mass was determined randomly

Comment: Someone wanting to diagnose your problem will want to know how your objects are rigged.  Provide details to some questions that an answerer would likely want to know: Which object is misbehaving? Does it have a rigidbody?  Does it have a collider?  Are there child objects?  Are they parented correctly?  Are any scripts tampering with the normal physics behaviour?  Be more specific about the observed undesirable behaviour.  "falls" and "fall downwards endlessly" are a little vague.  What was the expected behaviour?  Is it falling through the floor or something? Is the floor rigged correctly?

Comment: Learn Newtons Laws : "A body remains at rest, or in motion at a constant speed in a straight line, unless acted upon by a force"  What force is being used to stop the object from moving?

Comment: Add some details. Screenshot, Hierarchy and ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.